# Web Worker with dynamic importScripts values

Tags: web-worker

When defining a Web Worker, is it possible to construct the values passed to importScripts() dynamically?

My worker currently imports two scripts:

```
importScripts('lunr.min.js', 'underscore-1.5.0-min.js');
```

This works fine, but I want to implement bundling as well. I'd like to keep these files in the bundle, but to do that I'd need to use the bundle name instead of the individual files.

I've reviewed the [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#importing-scripts-and-libraries) and the [better](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) [articles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers#Importing_scripts_and_libraries) I can find, and I've tried a few different approaches, but nothing that's worked. There are some references to importScripts() being synchronous and if it's called as soon as a worker is new'ed up, I'm not sure if what I'd like to do is possible.

Comment: Define “implement bundling”.

Comment: By bundling I mean that, instead of using two separate JavaScript files in importScripts(), I'll need to point to my one bundled file that results from my bundling and minification process. In my dev environment, I'll have these two separate files, but when I deploy I'll bundle my libraries into one file. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do:

```
// array of script filenames
var scripts = ['lunr.min.js', 'underscore-1.5.0-min.js'];
```

And then call `importScripts` somehow so it imports all those scripts. You can do this as follows:

```
importScripts.apply(null, scripts);
```

This works because `importScripts` accepts multiple URLs as arguments.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not expressing myself very well. I appreciate your time!
 
In my dev builds, I'll have importScripts('lunr.min.js', 'underscore-1.5.0-min.js');
 
In my production builds I want to have something like importScripts('/bundles/lib?v=gCej6Km_nUiP5QKoo15Dw0rHSy5-XXYrfbE9inJ-fG01');
 
That bundle name can change, so I want to pass it in as a variable, perhaps when I create a new WebWorker or as a message. I've both researched it and tried, but it doesn't seem to be something I can change from outside of the worker.

Comment: @Mattio Hmm, maybe you could use [`workerify`](https://github.com/shama/workerify) then.

Answer (score 0):

Mattio,

take a look at the plugin [vkThread](http://eslinstructor.net/vkthread/)

In this plugin, you provide dependencies (import scripts) as an array of strings and you can easily manipulate with this array.

Let me know if you have any question.

--Vadim